# Table.Group gives duplicate keys

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a query like the following:

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({#"T1", #"T2", #"T3"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {
    {"T1.Col", each List.Min([T1Col]), type text},
    {"T2.Col", each List.Min([T2Col]), type text},
    {"T3.Col", each List.Min([T3Col]), type text}
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

I use it to find unique values of "Name" in all three source tables T1..T3 and and then pick some value from the three different source tables to check if there is any data from the original tables for this specific name.

After performing this operation, I expect to end up with unique values of "name", but I actually get a duplicate.

What is reason for this strange behavior? Not fixing value types in source tables? Bat character encoding? The different tables are loaded from excel sheets on various sharepoint sites, so bad data could be an issue, but I don't have the experience of PowerQuery to know what kind of bad inputs to look for.

And more importantly: how do I get unique values of Name while aggregating the original table?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that a trailing whitespace caused PowerQuery to create two different rows under `Table.group`, but the new table rows did not include the trailing whitespace making them into duplicate names.

I fixed the issue by transforming the script into

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({#"T1", #"T2", #"T3"}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Name", Text.Trim}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Trimmed Text", {"Name"}, {
        {"T1.Col", each List.Min([T1Col]), type text},
        {"T2.Col", each List.Min([T2Col]), type text},
        {"T3.Col", each List.Min([T3Col]), type text}
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

The downside is that I actually use the script for assessing data quality and proper use of the names, so I want to find the two names on different rows, with unique names, after the grouping. A longer term fix could be for me to transform names with trailing spaces into some other name with a suffix such as "_TRAIL", but just trimming whitespaces is good enough for now.